# Remove HTML markup when Posting to Chatter from flow

Tags: visual-workflow, chatter

When posting text from my flow to chatter it's putting the html in the chatter post. How do I prevent that from happening

sample of what it's posting from a display text field or if put in a variable first:

```
<p>The results of the requested transaction</p><br><p>Status: processed ok</p><br><p>status reason: n/a</p>
```

I do not want the html markup in the final posted text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the standard [Post to Chatter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_chatter.htm&type=5) flow action - you'll note it creates a [FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) record with the following value

`isRichText = false`

That field:

> Indicates whether the feed item Body contains rich text. If you post a
> rich text feed comment using SOAP API, set IsRichText to true and
> escape HTML entities from the body. **Otherwise, the post is rendered as
> plain text**.

So what are your options?

1. Don't use the standard chatter action and instead create the FeedItem record yourself with a Create Record element. Make sure to set `isRichText = true`
2. You could have a trigger (apex, flow) on FeedItem that sets `isRichText = true` and continue using the standard chatter post action
3. This one is a heavier lift and probably not needed if text is generally straightforward: Use invocable apex with [ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper) to post - you can see an unlocked package for doing so on unofficialsf - [Post Rich Chatter](https://unofficialsf.com/post-rich-chatter-invocable-action/)

An important note is **that not all HTML tags are supported** even when setting `isRichText = true`. For your text, you'll have to replace your `<br>` with `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Rich text supports the following HTML tags:

> - `<p>`
> - Though the `<br>` tag isn’t supported, you can use `<p>&nbsp;</p>` to
>   create lines.
> - `<a>`
> - `<b>`
> - `<code>`
> - `<i>`
> - `<u>`
> - `<s>`
> - `<ul>`
> - `<ol>`
> - `<li>`
> - `<img>`
> - The `<img>` tag is accessible only through the API and must reference files in Salesforce. Similar to this example: `<img src="sfdc://069B0000000omjh"></img>`

Comment: That's the magic right there. Thanks Kris!